# How to specify column order when using opencsv beanwriter?

Tags: java, opencsv

When using the `@CsvBindByName` annotation of OpenCSV and using a `StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder` to write out the actual csv i haven't found a method to specify the order of the columns.

Is it somehow possible to specify the column order whilst using bean to CSV mapping?

Comment: You can use @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Explained nicely by the post i duplicated.